# Neo4j performance in simple query when need to return all of the results

Tags: performance, neo4j, cypher

I am storing several sparse matrices in `Neo4j` when rows and columns are nodes that are connected between each other by relationships which store the matrix values. Lets' say that I just want to return one single matrix. `Neo4j` parses each single relationship and only then returns the data. That is very inefficient and takes huge amount of time. Is there a way to optimize such a query? I mean the query itself is very simple, and should not take long. Here is the query that I use that is very long:

```
MATCH (c:Cell {DATASET: { dataset }})-[ex:EXPRESSES]->(g:Gene)
RETURN c.cellId, g.geneName, ex.expr
```

It returns the matrix in a long form. Maybe if I could return it as a kind of blob in a short form, it would make things faster. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

> Update

I limited the number of items returned and was able to `PROFILE` the query. Here it is:

[image]

Comment: Can you provide some more examples of how the data looks like?

Comment: Sparse matrix. 90% of zeros in it, other values are floating point values. Each row is a node, each column is a node too. Each value (except for zeros, of course) creates a relationship between `row-node` and `column-node`. That is it. Several such matrices. I am storing the data as several adjacency lists. I want to get all of the data for one `DATASET`, one matrix.

Comment: Can you run a PROFILE of your query and add the query plan to the description, with all elements expanded?

Comment: Unfortunately no, because the browser crashes. The query can be run in `R` code but not in the browser.

Comment: When profiling, can you add `LIMIT 1` to the end of your query? That should finish quickly so that we can see the profile.

Comment: At the least can you confirm whether there's an index on :Cell(DATASET)?

Comment: Yep, there is, I created it right away

Comment: @cybersam ok, will try

Comment: The query seems very straightforward and should not be "slow". How many rows does it return? If it is large, you should look into tuning your [neo4j memory configuration](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/3.4/performance/memory-configuration/).